# PetSc installation Failed with MacPort can anyone help?

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, macports, finite-element-analysis

I'm trying to install **PetSc** with MacPorts. My final goal is to install **libMesh** on my Mac. When I'm trying to install PetSc its failing during configuration. I need to get PetSc installed before any attempt to install libMesh.

Here is the error part of the log.

```
:info:configure TESTING: checkFortranLibraries from config.compilers(/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_ports_math_petsc/work/petsc-3.1-p4/config/BuildSystem/config/compilers.py:624)
:info:configure *******************************************************************************
:info:configure                     UNABLE to EXECUTE BINARIES for config/configure.py 
:info:configure -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
:info:configure Cannot run executables created with C. If this machine uses a batch system 
:info:configure to submit jobs you will need to configure using/configure.py with the additional option  --with-batch.
:info:configure  Otherwise there is problem with the compilers. Can you compile and run code with your C/C++ (and maybe Fortran) compilers?
:info:configure *******************************************************************************
:info:configure 
:info:configure shell command " cd "/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_ports_math_petsc/work/petsc-3.1-p4" && /opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_ports_math_petsc/work/petsc-3.1-p4/config/configure.py --prefix=/opt/local --with-python --with-c-support=1 --with-c++-support=1 --with-pic=fPIC --with-shared=1 --prefix=/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_ports_math_petsc/work/destroot/opt/local/lib/petsc --with-cc=/opt/local/bin/openmpicc --with-cxx=/opt/local/bin/openmpicxx --with-mpiexec=/opt/local/bin/openmpiexec --with-hdf5=1 --with-hdf5-dir=/opt/local --LIBS=-lsz --with-triangle=1 --with-triangle-dir=/opt/local --with-debugging=1 " returned error 1
:error:configure Target org.macports.configure returned: configure failure: shell command failed (see log for details)
:debug:configure Backtrace: configure failure: shell command failed (see log for details)
while executing
"$procedure $targetname"
:info:configure Warning: the following items did not execute (for petsc): org.macports.activate org.macports.configure org.macports.build org.macports.destroot org.macports.install
:notice:configure Log for petsc is at: /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_ports_math_petsc/main.log
```

I'm running Mac OS 10.6.5 with Xcode 3.2.4. My MacPorts version is 1.9.2 the latest one.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be running up against [bug #237223](https://trac.macports.org/ticket/27223); adding `-lstdc++` to `LDFLAGS` might help, in that case. Also, make sure you have a working `gfortran` in your path. Consider filing a bug against the port over at MacPorts, as well.

The log file mentioned in the last line would help in diagnosing this, as would some of the context from the Python file that's running the test. Output from an attempted installation with the `-d` and `-v` flags passed to `port` might also help.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy for the information. Yes, the cause seems to be the same.